# How can I mute only system sounds via VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Is there any way to do this via VBScript?
I tried this but it mute speaker.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(chr(173))
```

Edit:
I solve the problem via add three more `shell.SendKeys"{TAB}"`

```
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.run"Sndvol"
WScript.Sleep 1500
shell.SendKeys"{TAB}"
shell.SendKeys" "
shell.SendKeys"%{F4}"
```

Final code is:

```
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.run"Sndvol"
WScript.Sleep 1500
shell.SendKeys"{TAB}"
shell.SendKeys"{TAB}"
shell.SendKeys"{TAB}"
shell.SendKeys"{TAB}"
shell.SendKeys" "
shell.SendKeys"%{F4}"
```

It would be nice if there was an easier way to do this anyway.